# Datepicker inside hidden divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, datepicker, hidden

I have certain divs that are hidden using jquery. Some of the divs have date input fields handled by datepicker.

Anytime I load my page, the browser gives this error:

Error: Unable to get value of the property 'inline': object is null or undefined

Datepicker is defined onReady

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    inline: true
});
```

I tried to hide the divs using .hide()/show() and addClass('hidden'). but datepicker gives this error anyway.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around `inline` like `'inline'`?

Comment: Maybe cause there's no "inline" option for datepicker? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#default

Comment: if there's no inline, how come the error doesn't display if I don't hide my div?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I solved it by replacing the updated jQuery css.

```
version : jquery-1.7.js
css: jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css
```

I resolved it by replacing the updated css:

```
css: jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery datepicker does not have the inline option.

If you want a datepicker inline, you must call datepicker() on a div, instead of an input.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>

Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>
```